# setBackgroundRGB not accepting function arguements Google app Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change the color of the cells when a number of conditions are met. Help me figure it out with Google sheets.

This is my code.

```
function myFunction() {

  const collorArray = [
      ['819', '156, 154, 69'],
      ['977', '202, 232, 87'],
      ['615', '22, 32, 44'],
    ];
  
  const rowStart = 3;
  const colStart = 1;

  const rowsCount = 9;
  const colsCount = 2;

  // get object
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange (rowStart, colStart, rowsCount, colsCount);
  var data = range.getDisplayValues();

  const dmcCol = 0;
  const codCol = 1;


  const myMap = new Map(collorArray);

  for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
    for (var i in data) {
      let row = data[i];
      let classDmc = row[dmcCol];
      let classColor = row[codCol];

      if (key === classColor) {
        classDmc.setBackgroundRGB(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my error

TypeError: classDmc.setBackgroundRGB is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because [setBackgroundRGB()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred,-green,-blue) is a method from the Range class.

On the other hand, `classDmc` comes from `row[dmcCol]`, which comes from `data`, but `data` is a 2-D array of strings, since it comes from [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).

So if you want to change the formatting, you need to work with the ranges, not the values.